# Ajuda com Select somando campos contas a pagar e receber para relatorio MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Galera tenho duas tabelas campos iguais, CONTAS A PAGAR e CONTAS A RECEBER, preciso gerar um relatório pegando o valor Credito - Debito e saindo resultado, alguém consegue me ajudar, estou apanhando pra isso, abaixo o select que estou usando e o link com print do resultado de testes que tenho no banco de dados.

https://www.cloudvine.com.br/exemplo.png

```
SELECT
tb_cr.tb_cr_credito AS tb_cr_credito,
tb_cr.tb_cr_id_fornecedor AS tb_cr_id_fornecedor,
tb_cr.tb_cr_dt_Lancamento AS tb_cr_dt_Lancamento,
tb_cr.tb_cr_vencimento AS tb_cr_vencimento,
tb_cr.tb_cr_descricao AS tb_cr_descricao,
tb_cr.tb_cr_valor AS Credito,
'' AS Debito,
tb_cr.tb_cr_situacao AS tb_cr_situacao
FROM tb_cr
WHERE tb_cr.tb_cr_situacao = 'Recebido'

UNION

SELECT
tb_cp.tb_cp_debito AS tb_cp_debito,
tb_cp.tb_cp_id_fornecedor AS tb_cp_id_fornecedor,
tb_cp.tb_cp_dt_Lancamento AS tb_cp_dt_Lancamento,
tb_cp.tb_cp_vencimento AS tb_cp_vencimento,
tb_cp.tb_cp_descricao AS tb_cp_descricao,
'' AS Credito,
tb_cp.tb_cp_valor AS tb_cp_valor,
tb_cp.tb_cp_situacao AS tb_cp_situacao
FROM tb_cp
where tb_cp.tb_cp_situacao = 'Pago'
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305445/consultar-dados-de-duas-tabelas-diferentes-e-listar-sem-unir-dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte estratégia:

- Ao invés de usar uma `String` vazia para as `Credito` e `Debito`, utilize 0, assim você pode utiliza-los como atributo de cálculo;
- Englobe toda a sua `query` em uma `subquery`;
- Utilize a cláusula `SUM` para obter os valores totais de cada coluna;
- Realize a operação baseada nessa soma;

Fazendo isso você terá algo como:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(tb_cr.tb_cr_valor) AS Credito
          FROM tb_cr
         WHERE tb_cr.tb_cr_situacao = 'Recebido') -
       (SELECT SUM(tb_cr.tb_cr_valor) AS Credito
          FROM tb_cr
         WHERE tb_cr.tb_cr_situacao = 'Pago') AS saldo
```

Veja functionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/448c36/1).

---

> [**`SUM([DISTINCT] expr) [over_clause]`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum)
>
> Returns the sum of `expr`. If the return set has no rows, `SUM()` returns `NULL`.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a some de uma `expressao`. Se o conjunto retornado não contiver linhas, `SUM()` retornará `NULL`.

Comment: Obrigado, me esclareceu bastante.