# Consulta SQL com 3 tabelas, somatório em 2 e agregação

Tags: sql

Olá.

Estou usando o banco de dados Firebird 2.5 e tenho 3 tabelas: **Clientes** (cadastro de cliente/pacientes); **Consultas** (consultas que os clientes realizaram); **Pagamentos** (informa os valores pagos pelos clientes).

Esta é a estrutura (básica) das 3 tabelas:

```
----------------
| CLIENTES     |
|--------------|
| idCli | Nome |
----------------

-------------------------------------
| CONSULTAS C                       |
|-----------------------------------|
| idCons | idCli | Data | ValorCons |
-------------------------------------

---------------------------------
| PAGAMENTOS P                  |
|-------------------------------|
| idPg | idCli | Data | ValorPg |
---------------------------------
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne uma outra tabela com os seguintes dados:

- nome do cliente (tabela CLIENTES)
- somatorio dos valores das consultas realizadas (tabela CONSULTAS)
- somatorio dos valores pagos pelo cliente (tabela PAGAMENTOS)
- saldo do cliente ((somatorio dos valores das consultas) - (somatorio dos valores pagos))

Gostaria de uma saida assim:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESULTADO                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Nome | SUM(C.ValorCons) | SUM(P.ValorPg) | SUM(C.ValorCons)-SUM(P.ValorPg) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Já tentei diversas variações do código abaixo (sem sucesso):

```
 SELECT consultas.idcli,
 SUM(consultas.ValorCons) as TotalCons,
 SUM(pagamentos.ValorPg) as TotalPg,
 SUM(consultas.ValorCons - pagamentos.ValorPg) as saldo,
 clients.nome
 FROM consultas
 LEFT JOIN clientes ON consultas.idcli=clientes.idcli
 LEFT JOIN pagamentos ON pagamentos.idcli=clientes.idcli
 GROUP BY consultas.idcli, clientes.nome
```

**Complementando a resposta do Sérgio Louro, o resutado ficou assim:**

```
SELECT
    clientes.nome,
    (SELECT SUM(ValorCons) FROM consultas WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) AS total_consultas,
    (SELECT SUM(ValorPg) FROM pagamentos WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) AS total_pagamentos
    ( (SELECT SUM(ValorCons) FROM consultas WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) - 
      (SELECT SUM(ValorPg) FROM pagamentos WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) ) as saldo
FROM clientes
```

Comment: Tem certeza que deveria ser um left join?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade não... Mas tentei de várias formas (RIGHT, INNER, FULL OUTER). Acredito que não seja desta forma (com dois JOIN) que se faz. Eu devo estar pensando errado...

Comment: Veja isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/523756/ajuda-com-select-somando-campos-contas-a-pagar-e-receber-para-relatorio-mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, dnat!

Você pode fazer isso utilizando subconsulta. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```sql
SELECT
    clientes.nome,
    (SELECT SUM(ValorCons) FROM consultas WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) AS total_consultas,
    (SELECT SUM(ValorPg) FROM pagamentos WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) AS total_pagamentos
FROM clientes
```

Comment: Oi Ségio, muito obrigado. Deu certo! Mas me ajude por favor a fazer a diferença das duas colunas **total_consultas** e **total_pagamentos**. Tentei adicionar abaixo do segundo select: `(SELECT SUM(consultas.ValorCons-pagamentos.ValorPg) FROM consultas,pagamentos WHERE consultas.idCli = clientes.idCli) AS saldo` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Olha só. Acho que consegui: `( (SELECT SUM(ValorCons) FROM consultas WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) - 
      (SELECT SUM(valorpago) FROM pagamentos WHERE idCli = clientes.idCli) ) as saldo`. Só não sei se está otimizado. Muito obrigado @Sérgio Louro.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65b645/1